# Creating/exporting multiple maps in one layout using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, interpolation, data-frame

I have an air pollution data that consists monthly mean values of 12 monitoring stations. I made interpolation and want to export the 12 different map in one layout with one legend. Since I am a newbie with ArcMap, I wonder if it is possible.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

*Edit:* I mean - how can I automate apply symbology and export layout (for E.g. to JPEG) processes, so I wouldn't have to repeat same processes multiple times.

Comment: go to insert pull down and select "data frame" - A new map appears. Add new layers and/or drag and drop layers from the other frame and then resize the frame as required.

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation could do with some expanding in this area but on the [Using data frames](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Using_data_frames/006600000004000000/) page it says:

> **Working with additional data frames**
>
> While in many maps, you'll only need one data frame, you can add more
>   data frames by clicking **Insert > Data Frame** on the main menu.

Your page layout will need 12 data frames (with data for one month displayed in each) and a single legend element created from any one of the 12 data frames (just be sure to classify your data the same in each of the data frames).